# SQL - Why am I getting an ORA-00918 Error? I defined a column that's duplicated

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00918

I'm trying to complete an exercise for an assignment for my Database Programming class using Oracle LiveSQL. I defined the column that appears in each of the 2 tables that are accessed. I do not understand why I'm getting the error. Where am I going wrong with my code?

```
SELECT 
    orders.customer_id,
    cust_email,
    COUNT(order_id) AS num_orders
FROM
    oe.customers
    LEFT JOIN oe.orders
        ON oe.customers.customer_id = oe.orders.customer_id
GROUP BY
    customer_id
ORDER BY
    customer_id ASC;
```

The table diagram with the 2 tables we are using:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, whatever columns appear in the `SELECT` clause must also appear in `GROUP BY`, unless those columns appear inside aggregate functions.  Consider using this version:

```sql
SELECT 
    c.customer_id,
    c.cust_email,
    COUNT(o.order_id) AS num_orders
FROM oe.customers c
LEFT JOIN oe.orders o
    ON c.customer_id = c.customer_id
GROUP BY
    c.customer_id,
    c.cust_email
ORDER BY
    c.customer_id;
```

Note also another problem you had was that `customer_id` is a column which appears in both tables.  You need an alias in order to qualify which table's column you want to include.

Comment: Why wouldn't customers.customer_id or orders.customer_id work since both tables have customer_Id? I tried what you suggested with adding alias and including cust_email in my group by statement and it worked but it did not work without aliases.

Comment: ...you answered your own question, the `customer_id` column appears in both tables, you need to tell Oracle which table you want to refer to.

Comment: What I mean is, we had a previous assignment with a similar JOINS problem where tables shared the column named `order_id` and adding `orders.order_id` would fix an ORA-00918 error

Comment: OK...I can't speak to a query which I can't see, you may be right.  In general, when doing a query involving more than one table, best practice is to _always_ use aliases.

Comment: `SELECT
    cust_last_name,
    cust_email,
    orders.order_id,
    product_id,
    quantity
FROM
    oe.customers
    LEFT JOIN oe.orders
        ON oe.customers.customer_id = oe.orders.customer_id
    LEFT JOIN oe.order_items
        ON oe.orders.order_id = oe.order_items.order_id
ORDER BY
    order_id ASC;`